# How to Automatically Copy Cells to Specific Locations in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a spending tracker that looks like this:
[Spending Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jPQR.png)

As you can see, each transaction is sorted consecutively by date and assigned an index number, with each transaction receiving its own row. Each transaction is essentially made of a "Store/Business/Person" text comment, a general text comment, an amount and a category. While this is all helpful information, you can imagine how it would likely get tedious to scroll to each category to enter the correct value.

My question is, what formulas can I use to copy information from a list such as in this sheet... [Input List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY9fY.png)

...into specific places within the main spreadsheet?

It is essentially a more complicated "='Input List'!C2" formula, however if the pasting destination can change based on if statements.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have both tables on the same sheet, you could try filling the value of each cell previously with the following formula according to the corresponding row in Spending Tracker table:

```
= IF('Input List'!F2="Option 1",'Input List'!E2)
```

where "Option 1" would be the selected category in the Input List table.